# How can I enable X.509 mutual authentification for only one user role in spring?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, x509

I've built a spring boot webapp with spring security and an angular frontend that consumes REST services from the spring application. I've got two user roles for now:

- User
- Admin

User and Admin shall authenticate via username and password, which is already working, but I'm not using the Spring user roles at all. Instead I build my own authentification via angular consumend rest services and tokens(JWT).
Now I want to add a Superadmin that accesses the same services as the admin but must authenticate using a client certificate (X.509).
How can I tell Spring to only authenticate using X.509, if the user is the superadmin?
Do I have to use Spring user roles for this?

Comment: no, you have to setup your front to only send certificate verification, if user has role superadmin :D but how do you want that if you're not logged in, so you don't know role yet? :) use different login point, where you use different credentials and require certificats on that point.

Comment: I want the superadmin to log in on the same page as user and admin. To acess the rest-services afterwards, the superadmin shall authenticate via certificate on every request.

Comment: if you pass it in headers, you can read specific header and check if it's null. If it's not empty - execute admin login, otherwise - userlogin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this is with a custom filter. In this case, you can extend the [X509AuthenticationFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/x509/X509AuthenticationFilter.html). You can override the filter's doFilter() method and modify the logic to perform a check on the type of user and then either call the doFilter() method from X509AuthenticationFilter or handle your JWT with your own AuthenticationProvider via the [AuthenticationManager](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationManager.html?is-external=true).

The following code samples show how you would create and integrate the custom X509AuthenticationFilter, but is not intended to be guide on how to enable X509 based authentication.

Sample WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private CustomX509AuthenticationFilter customX509AuthenticationFilter;

    @Autowired
    private  AuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(jwtAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.x509().x509AuthenticationFilter(customX509AuthenticationFilter);
    }
}
```

Sample Custom X509AuthenticationFilter:

```
@Component
public class CustomX509AuthenticationFilter extends X509AuthenticationFilter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    public CustomX509AuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if(isAdminUser(request)){
            super.doFilter(request, response, chain);
        }
        else {
            Authentication unauthenticatedToken = getUserCredentialsFromRequest(request);
            Authentication authenticatedToken = authenticationManager.authenticate(unauthenticatedToken);
            if(authenticatedToken.isAuthenticated()) {
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticatedToken);
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
            else {
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid Credentials");
            }
        }
    }

    private Authentication getUserCredentialsFromRequest(ServletRequest request) {
        // logic to retrieve user credentials from request and create initial Authentication
        return ...
    }

    private boolean isAdminUser(ServletRequest request) {
        // logic to determine whether or not user is admin
        return ...
    }
}
```